# Play record when operator pickup call

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

My description could be a little vague because I have not big experience in this field.

The problem is that my web service should do the following steps.

1. Another service send phone number in my web service
2. My web service takes that number and start calling into a particular queue in asterisk
3. After someone in this queue pickup call he\she should hear a recorded audio message
4. After that astersik should dial to the phone number from first step

Right now I can call to a local extension and then asterisk do the rest by calling to a client and connecting him with manager.

The first problem is that I don't know how to dial not to a local extension but to a queue in asterisk.

The second issue is how to play audio only when manager pick up call made from my web service.

Would be appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

IF you use freepbx, you should put message in Call Confirm Announce

If you use custom dialplan, you should use M option for dial command and create macro which will play needed file.

For dial queue in freepbx you have use queue_num@from-internal. No way give any suggestion for custom dialplan

Note: doing system like that without understanding asterisk internal can result hi bills for international calls becuase of hackers.